# Why does google variable exist when it has never been declared?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I was trying out the Google Maps API for Javascript, and came across the Hello World section.

```
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURAPIKEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

I noticed that `map = new google.maps.Map()` uses the variable google. If I try running just the javascript code using NodeJS, I would get a ReferenceError.

```
var map;

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
  zoom: 8
});
```

Why is there no `ReferenceError: google is not defined` occurring when run in in the html using a browser?

Comment: Because it's declared in the script you reference with `<script src="https://maps.googleapis...`. The very first line in the referenced script: `window.google = window.google || {};`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's declared in the script you reference with `<script src="https://maps.googleapis...`.

The very first line in the referenced script:

```
window.google = window.google || {};
```

The rest of the script builds all the objects within the `google` object:

```
google.maps = google.maps || {};
...
google.maps.Load = function(apiLoad) {
```

etc.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer! Can I also ask: where did the variable 'window' come from?

Comment: That's a built in object in the browser. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) for more information.